# How do I spawn objects on higher ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn, terrain

I have mountains, valleys and hills. But objects only spawn near valleys and in lower areas, not on hills:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResourceGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Spawn settings")]
    public GameObject resourcePrefab;
    public float spawnChance;

    [Header("Raycast setup")]
    public float distanceBetweenCheck;
    public float heightOfCheck = 1000f, rangeOfCheck = 30f;
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    public Vector2 positivePosition, negativePosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        SpawnResources();
    }

    void SpawnResources()
    {
        for(float x = negativePosition.x; x < positivePosition.x; x += distanceBetweenCheck)
        {
            for(float z = negativePosition.y; z < positivePosition.y; z += distanceBetweenCheck)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                if(Physics.Raycast(new Vector3(x, heightOfCheck, z), Vector3.down, out hit, rangeOfCheck, layerMask))
                {
                    if(spawnChance > Random.Range(0f, 101f))
                    {
                        Instantiate(resourcePrefab, hit.point, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, Random.Range(0, 360), 0)), transform);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well theres a height check value. Are you hills taller than that height check

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! Yeah its from 0 to 200 max i think. So when i change the Height check to a bigger height it only spawns them on places randomly where this height is near the number i chose for height of check... some lower and some a little higher but when i choose 40 for example there is none spawning at 0 or 200. How could i make it so the height of check is also a range?

Comment: so, surely the tutorial explained what the variables do? they also seem fairly well named?

Comment: I watched it 4 times now trying to find why it works that way but at some point he just goes: "this should work now" and did not give an explanation to for what does what exactly. It looks like the raycast looks at the whole terrain in small steps then for each step where the spawn check says yes it takes a hit point and spawns an object standing at this exact point and hight... but i dont understand what prevents this scan from happening at certain heights.

Comment: I mean it has something to do with the height of check variable.. there has to be some indicator which limits the check from happening to far away from the set height :()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

- your raycast is checking from a certain `heightOfCheck` downwards whether it hits your terrain / ground.
- Further it is limited to only check at a maximum distance of `rangeOfCheck` from that `heightOfCheck`.

=> For `rangeOfCheck` you should make sure it can even reach far enough down to hit your surface -> `rangeOfCheck` should be at least `>= heightOfCheck` depending whether your terrain can also have ground levels `< 0`.

So for instance it can only hit the ground at places where `ground level < heightOfCheck` and at the same time where the `rangeOfCheck` is big enough to reach down to the ground.

So assuming your terrain has only positive ground levels with a maximum height of `200` I would use something slightly bigger like e.g. `heightOfCheck = 205` and then ensure that `rangeOfCheck` can actually again reach `0` so I would again add a little buffer like e.g. `rangeOfCheck = heightOfCheck + 5;`.

The `5` is completely arbitrary - could be any positive value that ensures you start high enough and also end low enough, so you could use a single variable field and do e.g.

```
const float raycastBuffer = 5f;
public float maxTerrainHeight = 1000f;

void SpawnResources()
{
    ...

    var startPoint = new Vector3(x, maxTerrainHeight + raycastBuffer, z);
    if(Physics.Raycast(startPoint, Vector3.down, out var hit, maxTerrainHeight + 2 * raycastBuffer, layerMask))
            
    ...
}
```